# Discord.JS | function or way to delete an embed from a user message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am making a bot using the `Discord.JS API`. The bot basically plays the audio of a given youtube link (`ytdl-core`). Every time I type a link of what I want to play, the embed of the youtube link shows up. I know there are ways to disable embeds on the text channels, but I don't want to have to do that. Is there a way to delete *just* the embed?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't think you can't delete the embed without deleting the whole message. The other thing that I can think of is to turn off `post links` flags in the channel permissions for this channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually. If you wrap your link in less than and greater than signs (`<>`), an embed won't appear.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Glad I could help :)